# I am getting error in PostGIS 'function st_clip(raster, integer, geometry) does not exist'?

Tags: postgis, raster, postgis-raster

I have to find the count of the number of pixels in a given band of a clipped raster.
For clipping, I am using ST_clip(). Through clip function raster is clipped with a polygon.
 I am getting following error

> function st_clip(raster, integer, geometry) does not exist

I am not sure about the placements of the paranthesis.

`SELECT ST_ValueCount(ST_Clip(rast,1,ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((76.36792879303643 13.633268921278498,77.64804272121083 13.625811445922459,77.58727436708882 12.839858067425443,76.54887536367008 12.766426303994999,76.36792879303643 13.633268921278498))',4326), 4326)),1,false) AS valuecount FROM raster_file;`

**EDITED**

Should I use ST_UNION before ST_clip as my raster file is tiled and then saved in postgis using 'raster2pgsql' command.

Otherwise please provide a proper example to clip a raster from polygon, and to find the valuecount.

Comment: You have 4326 twice which may be part of the problem.

Comment: @JohnBarça What could be the query for clipping raster with a polygon and then find the valuecount.                                                    I am still getting same error after removing ST_transform.

Comment: You need ST_SetSrid not ST_Transform. Sorry missed that.

Comment: @JohnBarça, thanks for that. But my problem is improper placements of the paranthesis ( as I feels) because I am getting 'function st_clip(raster, integer, geometry) does not exist' as an error. And please check the question again as I have edited my issue.

Comment: Find the allowed syntax variants from http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Clip.html. Study your SQL command with a good editor like Notepad++ and identify what you have. It seems to be that the inner ST_Clip has syntax `ST_Clip([result from rast...],1,false)`. That is not on the list of good ones. Dropping "1" should make that part to pass.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem does not have to do with GIS. It is only about writing SQL with right syntax.

Comment: Agreed with @user30814

Comment: Should I delete this question ?

Comment: Try the query in format `SELECT ST_ValueCount(ST_Clip(rast,ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((76.36792879303643 13.633268921278498,77.64804272121083 13.625811445922459,77.58727436708882 12.839858067425443,76.54887536367008 12.766426303994999,76.36792879303643 13.633268921278498))',4326),false)) AS valuecount FROM raster_file;` I suggest to delete your question afterwards as too trivial.