# Function st_clip(raster, integer, geometry) does not exist

Tags: postgis, raster

I am trying to replicate [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/155974/calculating-mean-value-of-polygon-from-raster-in-postgis) example by alphabetasoup for summarizing pixel values according to census polygons, but am getting this error.

> ERROR:  function st_clip(raster, integer, geometry) does not exist
> LINE 8:   FROM (SELECT sa_id, ST_SummaryStats(ST_Clip(rast,1,geom)) ...
> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
> SQL state: 42883
> Character: 176

The code is only changed slightly to reflect my particular schemas, the results I'm querying, and to make it more legible.

```
WITH 
   polys AS (
       SELECT id As sa_id, geom
       FROM prac4.small_areas
    ),
   poly_stats AS (
       SELECT  sa_id, (stats).*
        FROM (SELECT sa_id, ST_SummaryStats(ST_Clip(rast,1,geom)) As stats
        FROM prac4.no2_raster
        INNER JOIN polys
        ON ST_Intersects(geom,rast) 
    ) As foo
    )

SELECT sa_id, SUM(mean*count)/SUM(count) As avg_pval
FROM poly_stats
GROUP BY sa_id
ORDER BY sa_id;
```

A similar question has been posted [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142131/i-am-getting-error-in-postgis-function-st-clipraster-integer-geometry-does) but I think the answers there had to do with incorrect SQL. I'm probably missing something obvious.

I'm on postgis 3.0.2., postgresql 12.4. The postgis_raster extension has been added to the database.

Comment: The ST_Clip function http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Clip.html takes just arguments raster, integer, and geometry. Are you sure that the installation of the raster extension was successful and you have ST_Clip available?

Comment: @user30184 on the contrary, it requires at least one more parameter, or an `INT[]`.

Comment: @user30184 although the description states otherwise...

Comment: I was looking at `raster ST_Clip(raster rast, integer nband, geometry geom, boolean crop);` and later `If crop is not specified, true is assumed meaning the output raster is cropped to the intersection of the geom and rast extents.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [docs](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Clip.html), `ST_Clip` doesn't provide the signature you use; without further evaluation of what you intend to do, the closest signature would be either

> raster ST_Clip(raster rast, integer nband, geometry geom, double precision nodataval, boolean crop=TRUE);

or

> raster ST_Clip(raster rast, integer nband, geometry geom, boolean crop);

Note that signatures with parameters having **no default** (`=<value>` suffix) requires an explicit input!

---

However, the docs explanations seem to disagree with the signatures, which may mean the docs have not been updated, or your installation is indeed not working...

Comment: Thanks so much! This did the trick! I must say, the error message is not particularly enlightening.

So, for anybody else who is as uninitiated about what a "signature" is as me (took me a while), changing "ST_Clip(rast,1,geom))" (as in alphabetasoup's example) to "ST_Clip(rast,1,geom,TRUE))" resolves the issue.

Just for future reference, how could I check whether I have any particular function available @user30184?

Comment: You can find the functions with PgAdmin from "Functions". With SQL try `SELECT * from pg_proc
where proname like '%st_clip%'`. I do not have raster extension installed and for me the query found only `"st_clipbybox2d"`.

Comment: Excellent - thanks a million!